# Google cloud speech library 1.8 does not work

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On my android phone, google cloud speech library give an error as like below.
is there any one who suffering with same issue?

```
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl: [Channel<1>: (speech.googleapis.com:443)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "io.grpc.internal.ConnectionClientTransport io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.newClientTransport(java.net.SocketAddress, io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory$ClientTransportOptions, io.grpc.ChannelLogger)"
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:49)
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:266)
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.obtainActiveTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:216)
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$SubchannelImpl.requestConnection(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1508)
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.PickFirstLoadBalancer.handleResolvedAddresses(PickFirstLoadBalancer.java:59)
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory$AutoConfiguredLoadBalancer.handleResolvedAddresses(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:155)
06-20 14:07:21.949 14926 15091 E ManagedChannelImpl:  at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener$1NamesResolved.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1378)
```

I tested with 0.4.1 build and it worked.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No.. looks most recent libraries does not support on Android device.